# Starting with a forward slash in html for "href"

Tags: html

I started learning html recently, and one thing that really confused me is why do some links have a forward-slash("/") before the path and some links don't?

ie.

```
<link href="/favicon.png" rel="icon">
<link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

vs.

```
<dt><a href="reset/index.html">Reset CSS</a></dt>
```

Is one a relative path and one an absolute path?  and how do href's work exactly? does it just stick on the path name after the base url?

Comment: Mark is correct, but I thought I would post a little info on how you can find these answers yourself if you really like looking at documentation.  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html >> click on a element >> click on href attribute >> click valid URL.  That explains URLs in the href attribute of an `a` element.  It also has links to the URL standard if you are really curious http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986.  RFCs and the HTML 5 standard can resolve a lot of questions.  They also tend to be more accurate than online blogs etc, but are definitely not as easy to read.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Is one a relative path and one an absolute path?

Yes.

If your browser is currently pointing at `http://foo/bar/baz.html` then:

- `<a href="reset/index.html">` would link to `http://foo/bar/reset/index.html`.
- `<a href="/reset/index.html">` would link to `http://foo/reset/index.html`.

---

If there is a [base element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) in the head of your HTML document then the relative path will be relative to the base. For example the link here will take you to `http://example.com/foobar/reset/index.html` regardless of where the page is located.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
   <TITLE>Base element example</TITLE>
   <BASE href="http://example.com/foobar/">
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
   <P><a href="reset/index.html">Reset CSS</a>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Adding a `base` example would be helpfull.

Comment: if there is no base specified, what's the default base?

Comment: @buffer Yes. For any page of `stackoverflow.com` domain, `/` URL is the same as `stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: How does `canonical` fit into this topic? e.g. `<link rel="canonical" href="/wiki/HTML/Kopfdaten/meta" />` or `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/content.html">`

Comment: And what is about root URLs like `https://foo.bar.org`. Is the beginning `/` translated to `https://foo.bar.org` or `https://bar.org`?

Comment: Real example `//cdn.jamanetwork.com/UI/app/img/favicons/jama/favicon.ico`. Looks relative because of beginning `/` but it is not.