# Unable to load require.config dependency when using with Django

Tags: django, requirejs

I'm using Backbone and Django in a project.  Initially I wanted to use Backbone views throughout the site to render my HTML content, however, there was a CRUD page that required FILE uploads and stuff so I decided to use the Django to render the site.

Now, since the form is at the url /item/article/new (http://localhost/item/article/new/), when I load up the page, it is unable to locate the requirejs dependency as stated in the config.js file.  Just so that it's clear, the require.js script tag is like such:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/libs/require/require-jquery.min.js" data-main="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/config"></script>
```

My config.js file:

```
require.config({

  // Set base url for paths to reference
  baseUrl: 'static/js',

  // Initialize the application with the main application file.
  deps: ['main'],
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/require/require-jquery.min',
    ...
    ...
  }
})
```

Now, since my baseUrl is set to static/js, when I navigate to /item/article/new, it complains that it could not find `http://localhost/item/article/new/static/js/main.js`.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try appending forward slash at start to your baseUrl `/static/js`.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending forward slash at start to your baseUrl `/static/js`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find what I was doing wrong and your answer helped me! But why does it depend on the slash so heavily?

Comment: @DmitryWojciechowski see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href) this will clarify your confusion.