# Creating links without actually putting the whole link in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been wondering how do other websites do their navigation links.
What most beginners like me do is put the whole link inside the  tag

```
<a href="www.example.com/news.html">News</a>
```

or something like this:

```
<a href="news.html">News</a>
```

But I've seen a lot of websites lately that does this:

```
<a href="/news.html">News</a>
```

and then the browser address bar display it like this

#### http://www.example.com/news/

First I want to know how do you call this method? and what are the advantages of doing this. and lastly, how does it actually work?.

I want to research about it but I don't know what to type on google. I did try a lot of keywords I could think of that relates to this but nothing comes close to what I'm looking for

Comment: The second example you show will link to `news.html` within the same folder of the current page. The third example will link to the root of the web.

Comment: Your first example has an Absolute URL. The second one uses a relative URL. Learn the differences between the two before using on or the other.

Comment: Duplicate question --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href

Comment: I see, Is it better to put it in a separate folder? for example you have, (Home, Latest, Genre)  in your main navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 4 basic link types:

self-link: `href=""`. This is a short-hand form of "link to yourself". You'll see it used for in-page anchors, such as `href="#top"` and the link.

relative: `href="news.html"`. Clicking on this will try to load a `news.html` page in the SAME directory as the page that the link is contained in, so if you're on `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`, you'll be trying to load `http://example.com/foo/news.html`.

local absolute: `href="/news.html"`. This will try to load a `news.html` page from the document root of the site. If you're on `http://example.com/foo/bar/html`, you'll be trying to load `http://example.com/news.html`. The leading `/` is what makes this a local absolute instead of a relative path.

full absolute: `href="http://example.com/news.html"`. A full-blown url, which can point to a completely different site if need be. It CAN be point to the exact same site you're on, but essentially it's a "go over there, no matter where over there is".

Answer (score 0):

The best practice (for me?) is the first one, you need to write all the URL for the most readable code..

The first and the 3rd link are the same if you are on the same domain name..

The 2nd is different, if you are on www.example.com/index.html you'll go to www.example.com/news.html..
But if you are on www.example.com/categoy/index.html you'll be redirected to www.example.com/categoy/news.html and not on root directory.

But I don't understand why you talk about /news/ directory ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with HTML, not JavaScript. Your first snippet uses an absolute path. The second two use relative paths. For more information, read this: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: actually, the first one is relative too, since it's missing http://. not like the user has a www.example.com subdir, but it's still going to be treated as a subdir.

Answer (score 0):

Relative URL's will probably get you some results.

- `news.html` will navigate relative to your current location
- `/news.html` will navigate relative to the root domain name

For example if your current location is `http://example.com/sub/` :

`href="news.html"` will get you to `http://example.com/sub/news.html`

but

`href="/news.html"` will get you to `http://example.com/news.html`

See also http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html#h-5.1.2