# servlet doGet is launched twice through servlet annotation calling

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

For some reasons my servlet doGet method is being called twice.
I am calling servlet from the index.jsp page by using servlet annotation "/Profile/*. And it passes path as localhost:1919/**Profile/username** to getPost method.

```
<li><a href="Profile/<%=lg.getUsername()%>">Your Profile</a></li>
```

Servlet Profile retrieves data from the java container stores it as an attribute and forwards to profile.jsp page.

```
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/profile.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("ProfileInfo", proInfo);

            rd.forward(request, response);
```

My profile.jsp page uses java code to show all the data (and it shows it perfectly). 
But then I click link to the next update_profile.jsp page. Just simple link. Then I realize that on this step for strange reasons for me doGet method from Profile servlet is called the second time. And passes path as localhost:1919/**Profile/update_profile.jsp**

Here is my profile.jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="uk.ac.dundee.computing.aec.instagrim.containers.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Picturize - User Profile</title>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h2>Picturize - Profile of user</h2>
</header>
<%
    ProfileInfo proInfo = (ProfileInfo) request.getAttribute("ProfileInfo");
%>
<article>

    <h2>User: <%=proInfo.getUsername()%>
    </h2>

    <h3>First name: <%=proInfo.getFirstname()%>
    </h3>

    <h3>Last name: <%=proInfo.getLastname()%>
    </h3>

    <h3>Email address: <%=proInfo.getEmail()%>
    </h3>

    <a href="update_profile.jsp">Update your profile information</a>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

And update_profile.jsp file is just simple file with `<h1>hello</h1>` output.

I have looked in the internet that this might be a mapping problem or my css relative path connection problem. As you see I have commented out my css connection and problem still exists.

My run output in the IDE also shows these errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /profile.jsp at line 27

24: %>
25: <article>
26: 
27:     <h2>User: <%=proInfo.getUsername()%>
28:     </h2>
29: 
30:     <h3>First name: <%=proInfo.getFirstname()%>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at uk.ac.dundee.computing.aec.instagrim.servlets.Profile.displayProfile(Profile.java:116)
    at uk.ac.dundee.computing.aec.instagrim.servlets.Profile.doGet(Profile.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.profile_jsp._jspService(profile_jsp.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 38 more
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
    <description>MySQL Test App</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uk.ac.dundee.computing.aec.instagrim.servlets.Profile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>picturizedb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

And my tomcat run configuration settings: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZXQ2R3O8B8SERPYzJxZFViLVE/view?usp=sharing
and
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZXQ2R3O8B8THE3TGFnUFVpNjg/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the problem has to do with the way you mapped your servlet and the way you want to access your pages.

So your root url is: `http://localhost:1919/`

When you first open profile (using this code `<a href="Profile/<%=lg.getUsername()%>">`) browser makes an access to `http://localhost:1919/Profile/xyz`. This call invokes the servlet, since it is mapped to parse all requests starting with `/Profile`.Till now everything is working like you expect.

At this point your url in browser looks like: `http://localhost:1919/Profile/xyz`. Now, you click on the link to update the user and the browser appends `update_profile.jsp` to `http://localhost:1919/Profile/`, so the url looks like `http://localhost:1919/Profile/update_profile.jsp`, but the problem is, it still begins with `/Profile` and **still fits the servlet mapping** you have defined in `web.xml`.. So the servlet is obviously invoked..

Solutions:

1) Define in web.xml a new servlet, with more specific url, which will handle your update request(check more about servlet url pattern matching [here](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html)).

2) In case there is no logical relation between `Profile` path and `update_profile.jsp` (which looks to me unlikely from the  code logic) you could use `/` in `href` (something like `<a href="/update_profile.jsp">`) which will make browser to make a request to `http://localhost:1919/update_profile.jsp` instead of `http://localhost:1919/Profile/update_profile.jsp`.

EDIT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href) is also nice example of how the `/` in urls should be used.