# Cannot get jQuery to work (working offline)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to this site and to jQuery and I have a problem that is probably very simple but I cannot for the life of me solve it. I am running "index.html" from my computer and jquery.js (downloaded from jquery's website) is absolutely in the same folder and it seems to be referenced correctly in my code.

It was only meant to be a simple thing of clicking on a div and it would fade out. I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

Sorry if this is a really basic question, I have looked around the site and searched a lot.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('div').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ou43epos/

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it not do anything? Or does it fade out every div instead of the one that's clicked? (Because that's what the code does.) If you look in the browser's JavaScript console do you see any errors there? If you look in the console's network tab do you see all files loaded correctly?

Comment: Check for any errors on the console.

Comment: Check `browser's console` for error, and top of it, verify `resources` in browser, if jQuery is present or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The leading slash makes your browser look in the file system root. Without the slash, it'll load from the current (index.html) directory.

Comment: It would be great if you also explained why this might help.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it! It was simple.. I put "/" before script and jquery. I didn't realise I could use the network tab to see what files were loaded.

Such a basic error but it drove me crazy for a long time! Such is life :).

Thanks all (especially @Juhana)

Answer (score 0):

Using `src="/jquery.js"` to load your scripts results in your browser trying to load `file:///C:/jquery.js`. Change it to `src="jquery.js"`.

As Mark Byers said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10659501/1414639):

> If your browser is currently pointing at http://foo/bar/baz.html then:
>
> • `<a href="reset/index.html">` would link to `http://foo/bar/reset/index.html.`
>
> • `<a href="/reset/index.html">` would link to `http://foo/reset/index.html`.