# How to write javascript for reference image url for to write image and show on any page that use same script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website has the following structure:

```
root            --> such as localhost or example.com or file:///... etc.
|--css
|--image
: |--folder     --> root/image/folder/
|--js
: |--script.js  --> root/js/script.js
|--page
: |--index.html --> root/page/index.html
|--index.html   --> root/index.html
```

I use jQuery to write images for `root/index.html` and save to `root/js/script.js`

```js
var db = {
    "images" : [
        {"image-url": "image/folder/myImage.png"},
        {"image-url": "image/folder/myImage.png"},
        {"image-url": "image/folder/myImage.png"}
    ]
}

$.each(db.images, function (key, data) {
    var image = data['image-url'];
    $('body').append('<image src="' + image + '" />');
}
```

It works correctly. My images are displaying. I'll try to create `index.html` in `root/page` and use `../js/script.js` on this page.
But it's seem not display any image. On browser show blank box of image. I'll try to look at F12 and found `image-url` return this value.

```
GET root/page/image/folder/myImage.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

But I want to reference my image at `root/image/folder/myImage.png`. I don't know how to write the script for reference image url for to write image and show on any page that use same script. Can't someone to fix this problem.
Thank in advance and sorry for my skill.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'll to edit them.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have several static images, then it would be better to use CSS:

If you have a `background-image` definition in your CSS file, then it will work for any relative path.

CSS (`root/css/site.css`):

```
.some-image {
     background-image: url('../image/your-image.png`);
}
```

Now, if you include this in `root/index.htm` and `root/page/index.htm`, it will work for both of them.

2. If your images are dynamic and are generated by PHP or whatever else, you can use the following URLs:

   ```
   var db = {
       "images" : [
           {"image-url": "/image/folder/myImage.png"},
           {"image-url": "/image/folder/myImage.png"},
           {"image-url": "/image/folder/myImage.png"}
       ]
   };
   ```

There is a leading slash in URL. I.e., the result is the following:

```
<img src="/image/folder/myImage.png"/>
```

It it an absolute-path reference. The URL will be calculated from the root of domain.
For example, for `http://localhost` it will be `http://localhost/image/folder/myImage.png`, and it will be the same for any page in your host.

Notice that,
- If your site is located in a subfolder, an absolute URL will still point to the root folder
- For `file` protocol `/` will point to the root of your drive

You can use `BASE` tag to specify your base URL.

Read more about it at [this Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href) and [this Webmasters Stackexchange topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls).

Comment: I'll try to use 2nd way and come back to tell my result.

Comment: I try on local strorage such as `G:/something` and browser return `/` as drive letter only such as `file://G:/image/folder/myImage.png` not `file://G:/something/image/folder/myImage.png` and I found this error on my console `GET file://G:/image/folder/myImage.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: @phongphan117 It won't work for local file storage, yes. There is no way you can define a relative path to the "root" folder of your web-site on a local storage withotu CSS. Use local server instead.