# Anchor tag href is not navigating with single slash but with double

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am facing a problem where my absolute url is not clickable in anchor tag like below :-

```
   <a href="/account/login"><Login</a>
```

But with double slash it is working:-

```
   <a href="//account/login"><Login</a>
```

but with double slash URL is not right.

Thanks,
Sombir

Comment: are you running this on a server, or what?More detail please

Comment: `/account/login` is not an absolute URL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute

Answer (score 1):

Here is some reference links which will help you to resolve your issue. Please have a look at these links:

- [Two forward slashes in a url/src/href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute)
- [Starting with a forward slash in html for "href"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href)

Hope these links will help you.