# Relative paths for a 404 page served with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm serving a 404 page with Express:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).sendFile('404.html', { root: __dirname + BASE })
})
```

The `404.html` is located in the website's root, and everything work flawlessly if I try to open a non-existent page on the root
(`http://mywebsite.com/asd`).

Problem is when I try to open a page inside other folders (`http://mywebsite.com/asd/asd`). The paths for my `css` and `js` aren't respected:
`<link href="dist/bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

How to solve this path related problem? And is it safe to to serve the page with `sendFile` on a production server?

Comment: I would say that the paths _are_ respected, they just aren't correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need a forwardslash in front of your `href` link:

```
<link href="/dist/bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As `/` is interpreted as the root of the hostname:

- `dist/bundle.min.css` is relative to the path.
- `/dist/bundle.min.css` is relative to the root.

Edit: Right. If you specify a base, then the root is set to that base. :)

Comment: It seems like `/dist` tries to search for the files in the root of the project (the folder where I keep the gulpfile.js and package.json) when I run the app in localhost mode!

Comment: It should resolve to `http://mywebsite.com/dist/bundle.min.css` or `localhost:port/dist/bundle.min.css`. The first forwardslash means it is based on the root. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/5812121 http://stackoverflow.com/a/10659501/5812121

Comment: Your answer is correct, thanks! My error was also declaring BASE to spin up the server! ```server.use(BASE, express.static(__dirname + BASE, {
  extensions: ['html']
}))```