# CSS doesn't render on deployment

Tags: css, github-pages, hugo

I deployed to github-pages my gokarna-themed Hugo blog, but for some reason, it doesn't render the CSS on the page.

It works just fine when I run it on my localhost.

Here is the link to the repository: https://github.com/seamIess/mfp

And this is how it looks like: https://seamiess.github.io/mfp/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your stylesheet import to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

In this example, I removed the first slash from the href. You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659459/starting-with-a-forward-slash-in-html-for-href).

Edit: I see the site is now fixed - most likely from moving the moving the stylesheets or changing the routing. So now keeping the first `/` is how the href should be setup.